# Add item to Sharepoint Survey list

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a survey list in sharepoint and I'd like to add an answer to the survey using c# code, this I think could be interpreted as add an item to the list so I tried the next but is not working.

How can this be done?

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://user-pc"))
{
    using (SPWeb web = site.RootWeb)
    {
        try
        {
            SPList olist = web.Lists["JobSchedulle"]; //<- Name of the survey in sharepoint 2010
            SPListItem item = olist.Items.Add();
            item[5] = "good";// <- this survey only has one question, and is a text option ..
            item.Update();

        }
        catch {
            Console.ReadLine();         
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error - the code works, but I was accessing `item[5]` (with the wrong index).